# How to find out size of my POST request for yandex.tank ammo?

Tags: yaml, stress-testing, yandex-tank

I create on my own ammo for Yandex.Tank:

```
POST /some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: some.host
Content-Length: 169
Connection: Close

{
  "some": "json"
}
```

As I get from documentation and some examples from the internet - the first line in ammo.txt file must be a size of my request.

I've tried to count this size on my own and used some online services (found by request `text to byte` or something) and get value `271`.
Tank throws this error:

```
<class 'yandextank.stepper.module_exceptions.AmmoFileError'>: Error while reading ammo file. Position: 4, header: '271', original exception: list index out of range
```

Also, I tried to count the size of example requests and get different values that were in those examples.

Seems I am doing it wrong.

There is load.yaml just for be sure:

```
phantom:
#  ssl: true
  address: some.host
#  port: '443'
  port: '80'

  load_profile:
    load_type: rps
    schedule: const(100, 5m)

  timeout: '60'
  instances: 100500

  ammo_type: uripost
  ammofile: ammo.txt

uploader:
  enabled: true
  package: yandextank.plugins.DataUploader
  api_address: https://overload.yandex.net
  token_file: token.txt
  job_name: "test"
  job_dsc: "test"

autostop:
  autostop:
    - net(110, 10, 5)
    - http(503, 10, 5)

telegraf:
  enabled: false
```

Question: how to correctly count the size of my ammo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add marker after request size, e.g:

```
yyy marker
POST ...
```

And tank returns me `read xxx bytes instead of yyy`.
Found solution in some random presentation about Yandex.Tank. 
Hope this will help to someone in future.